# How can I spawn a shape every x seconds in codeskulptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, codeskulptor

I want to draw to the canvas a ball every second from a list of balls using a timer_handler on Codeskulptor. I am unable to get anything drawn to the screen please help.

```
balls = []
#balls = [ randBall() for i in range(totalBalls) ]

def time_handler():
    global newBalls, balls
    balls.append(randBall() for i in range(totalBalls))

interaction = Interaction(balls)

frame = simplegui.create_frame("Test", CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)
timer = simplegui.create_timer(1000, time_handler)

frame.set_draw_handler(interaction.draw)
frame.start()
timer.start()
```

Comment: I think that is the good way. The timer do the job, every second. Now you need to draw with a draw handler.

Post a complete code with a link to CodeSkulptor and I will see it.

(By the way the global statement is useless, because these variables themselves are not modified.)

Comment: Thank you for your concern Olivier but I have finally managed to get it working!